# Find unused variables

Tags: eclipse, verilog, system-verilog, cadence

I'm using the following tools for programing in verilog+system-verilog and I'm wondering which can detect which variables are not being in use:

- Eclipse
- Eclipse DVT extension
- Cadence tools

Comment: You may want to try Cadence IFV, the static formal verification tool - it can detect unused variables and even uninitialized variables

Comment: @AldoT what's the difference between IFV and HAL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think DVT can detect unused variables, but AMIQ have another product called Verisimo that can do this, AFAIK.

Also, try using the HAL (HDL Advanced Linter) from Cadence to see if they support this (it's a pretty basic thing for a linter).